# How to update my html when the DB returns a value ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, database

```
<script>
function show(shown, hidden) {
  document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block';
  document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none';
  return false;
}
</script>

<body>

  <div id="Page1">
    Content of page 1
    <br><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>
  </div>

  <div id="Page2" style="display:none">
    Content of page 2
    <br><br>
    <a href="#" onclick="return show('Page1','Page2');">Show page 1</a>
  </div>

</body>
```

In this code you see that 
`<a href="#" onclick="return show('Page2','Page1');">Show page 2</a>`
this code jump to page 2.

This code works fine but I need to do a little diffrent.When my db returns a value like 3,I want to jump the third page or if my db returns value of 2 I want to jump the second page. So my main problem is how can I take the return value and use it in this code ?

`<a href="#" onclick="return show('valueofreturn','Page1');">Show page return value</a>`

Comment: How do your db *returns* a value ? Where do you put it, in the `onclick` attribute ? We need more info.

Comment: When your db returns a value ?

Comment: I defined some rules on my DB. I have a survey html page so for example if I choose b)Wednesday my db returns 2 and in that time I need to jump to page 2 or if I choose c)Sunday my db returns 3 and in that time I need to jump page 3.

Comment: @gypsyCoder after I choose the answers on my survey page and then I click the Next Button so in that time my class check my rules and then returns a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a JSON call to retrieve the data from your server, then in the success handler, hide all pages and then show the one you want :

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/test.json", function( data ) {
    $('.page').hide();
    $('#page' + data.pageid ).show();
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use a JSON call to retrieve the data from my db.Can you help me to make this :)

Comment: It really depends on what your server side architecture is.  E.g. If you are using  MS then you would implement a Web API2 endpoint that makes the call to the DB and returns the page number model.  However, there are a myriad of server configs & DB providers out there and you haven't indicated anything but "database"

Comment: <script> 
function show(shown, hidden) { 
$.ajax({ 
type:'GET',
 dataType: "json", 
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 url:'C:\wamp\www\post.php', success: function(result) { 
result.returnvalue; 
if(result.targetPage>0){ 
shown = result.targetPage;
 }
 document.getElementById(shown).style.display='block'; document.getElementById(hidden).style.display='none'; 
console.log(result); }, 
});
 return false;
 } 
</script>
how can I equal my return value into the result.targetPage ?

Comment: If you're using jQuery (the $) to make the Ajax call, use it to do the selection, and show and hide work for you.

Comment: Thank you for everything :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Get data from server side.

You can use Ajax to create asynchronous Web applications. Ajax can send data and retrieve from a server, e.g., RESTful API.

2. show/hide "div"

If you want to show Page1 and hide Page2.

```
 $("#Page1").show(); 
 $("#Page2").hide();
```

3. Java Server
   You can use JavaBeans / JSP to do this work.

> References.
>
> http://api.jquery.com/show/
>
> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/